# Cucumber detects all scenarios but ignores them

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, cucumber

I am trying to use cucumber to test a Spring-Boot & Kotlin app. I am running into the problem that cucumber is running all the scenarios in the feature file, but it ignores them, and does not print the stubs (which I have defined already).

The directory structure is:

```
src/test
├── kotlin
│   └── com
│       └── xxx
│           └── car
│               └── controller
│                   ├── CarControllerTestRunner.kt
│                   └── steps
│                       └── StepDefinitions.kt
└── resources
    ├── features
    │   └── car
    │       └── controller.feature
    └── mockito-extensions
        └── org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
```

My POM:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

the test runner class:

```
package com.xxx.car.controller

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions
import org.junit.Ignore
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner


@RunWith(Cucumber::class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = ["src/test/resources/features/car/"],
        glue = ["com.xxx.car.controller.steps"],
        plugin = ["summary", "pretty"])
class CarControllerTestRunner


@Ignore
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
open class SpringCucumberIntegrationTests
```

and finally the test log:

```
Test ignored.

Test ignored.

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m15.280s

Oct 21, 2019 4:11:11 AM cucumber.runtime.java.ObjectFactoryLoader loadSingleObjectFactory
INFO: Loading ObjectFactory via service loader: io.cucumber.spring.SpringFactory
04:11:12.083 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.xxx.car.controller.StepDefinitions], using SpringBootContextLoader
04:11:12.088 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.xxx.car.controller.StepDefinitions]: class path resource [com/xxx/car/controller/StepDefinitions-context.xml] does not exist
04:11:12.088 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.xxx.car.controller.StepDefinitions]: class path resource [com/xxx/car/controller/StepDefinitionsContext.groovy] does not exist
04:11:12.088 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.xxx.car.controller.StepDefinitions]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
04:11:12.089 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.xxx.car.controller.StepDefinitions]: StepDefinitions does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
04:11:12.144 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.xxx.car.controller.StepDefinitions]
04:11:12.152 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'systemProperties' with lowest search precedence
04:11:12.153 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'systemEnvironment' with lowest search precedence
[...]
```

The spring application does start up, but then shuts down immediately without any of the scenarios being executed. I've searched SO extensively, but none of the questions directly apply to my situation, or the suggested answers did not fix my problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have your `SpringCucumberIntegrationTests` annotated with `@Ignore` and `@SpringBootTest`? The former shouldn't be needed and the latter should be moved to a class with defines steps.

Comment: I was basing my implementation off this article:
[Spring Boot REST Service Integration Testing Using Cucumber](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-rest-service-integration-testing-using)

needless to say, I am trying to set this up for the first time.

Comment: You'll have to put a break point in the `Cucumber` class and see why it doens't find your features.